# AttributeError: module 'bs4' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bs4.py", line 1, in <module>
    import  bs4
  File "/home/mhadi/Desktop/bs4test/bs4.py", line 5, in <module>
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site,'lxml')
AttributeError: module 'bs4' has no attribute 'BeautifulSoup'
```

The code:

```
import  bs4
import urllib.request

site = urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8000').read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site,'lxml')
#for i in site: 
#    print(site[i])
print(soup)
```

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and then use directly `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I think you should not name your file `bs4` since it causes confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your **filename is `bs4.py`**. Now if you write an `import` statement, Python will first look for local files with that name. So it assumes that your `import bs4` refers to your own file. Your file will thus aim to import itself, but it obviously does not contain the desired module.

A **quick fix** is renaming the file. For instance into `bs4tests.py`. Then you can use `import bs4`.

Alternatively, you can for instance try to remove the local path, like:

```
import sys               # import sys package
old_path = sys.path[:]   # make a copy of the old paths
sys.path.pop(0)          # remove the first one (usually the local)
import bs4               # import the package
sys.path = old_path      # restore the import path
```